# C# Regex first letter capital the rest lower case

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex that returns true if the first letter is capitalized and the rest are lower case.  However, the method I wrote always returns false.  What is wrong with my regex and what changes should I make.
Here is my code.

```
public bool VerifyName(string name){
     Regex rgx = new Regex("^[A-Z][a-z]+$");
     return rgx.Equals(name);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the `Equals` method, which will compare your string for *equality* with the regex object. This will never be true, it's like comparing apples and oranges. Use `IsMatch` instead.

And you could also improve the regex by adding Unicode support:

```
^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*$
```

If we simplify the code a bit we get:

```
public bool VerifyName(string name)
    => Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*$");
```